# How to determine the base of stratus clouds?

Tags: weather, theory

For cumulus clouds this applies

1. Calculate the 'spread,' where you're taking the current surface temperature and subtracting the dew point.
2. Divide the spread by 4.4 (if temperatures are in °F) or 2.5 (if temperatures are in °C), then multiply by 1000. This will give you cloud base in feet above ground level.

But what about stratus clouds?

Comment: This is pretty much a purely meteorological question, and while weather does apply to aviation, (as I have argued before...) this one is off topic.  VTC.

Comment: Maybe if you added "Do pilots flying big airlines care about..." it would be on topic?  (but then the answer would be "no", and you wouldn't learn how to do your calculation.)

Comment: There is something wrong with that formula for cumulus' bases; I would say it's wrong by about a factor of 3 (it gives bases three times as high as reality).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no formula for determining the height of the base of stratus clouds based on the ground-level temperature and dewpoint (or relative humidity).  Unlike convective cumulus clouds, stratus clouds are not formed by parcels of air rising up from the ground.  (Actually, cumulus clouds are not *always* formed by air rising from ground level either, but they *usually* are.)

Comment: Just a note to emphasize the right word: stratus clouds are not formed by parcels of air rising up from the **ground**.  Stratus (and cumulus) are caused by rising air, it's just that the source parcel for both may or may not be near ground level.